# Solr/SolrJ: How do you Highlight non-text fields?

Tags: solr, solrj

I have been successful in enabling highlighting on Text based field types, but not for non-text field types...

How does one configure solr to highlight non-text field types? I cannot find a example on the web for non-text fields. Is it even possible?

Specifically I want to highlight the Date value in the document that meets the query.

I am using solrJ to peform the query, could it be the limiting factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlighting is not possible on non "text" fields. Look at this:

```
/**
   * Returns a collection of the names of all stored fields which can be
   * highlighted the index reader knows about.
   */
  public Collection<String> getStoredHighlightFieldNames() {
    if (storedHighlightFieldNames == null) {
      storedHighlightFieldNames = new LinkedList<String>();
      for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
        try {
          SchemaField field = schema.getField(fieldName);
```

Especially here:

```
          if (field.stored() &&
                  ((field.getType() instanceof org.apache.solr.schema.TextField) ||
                  (field.getType() instanceof org.apache.solr.schema.StrField))) {
```

until here

```
            storedHighlightFieldNames.add(fieldName);
          }
        } catch (RuntimeException e) { // getField() throws a SolrException, but it arrives as a RuntimeException
            log.warn("Field \"" + fieldName + "\" found in index, but not defined in schema.");
        }
      }
    }
    return storedHighlightFieldNames;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Although it is as i feared :(

Comment: How would one then identify which non-text fields caused the document to meet the query?

Comment: You mean probably which non-text fields matched a part of the query. Afaik there is no implementation for returning direct matches.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am not sure that we are talking about the same thing however...

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am not sure that we are talking about the same thing however... Say i have a document that has two text fields A="aaaaa" and B="sssss" and one date field D=20100101. A user initaited query is requested( A:blah AND D:20100101 ). It returns the document, but i do not know what field in the document met the query (i.e. the date) as there is no highlighting for the date.

Comment: Exactly that is what i meant. There is no builtin functionality to test which field met the query in e.g a query like: ADATE:something OR BDATE:something OR CDATE:something

Comment: ah, thats a pity. thanks for all your help. I'll just have to tell ask the client whether they would prefer to remove / modify the requirement related to highlighting or to increase the cost estimate due to having to either extend default solr or to do some post processing to determine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this as was explained.

But it's super simple to adapt Solr to handle this. Create another field for your date but in string format. Now just use a copyField:

```
<field name="date1" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="date1_str" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<copyField source="date1" dest="date1_str"/>
```

Then just add the field date1_str to your query.